# JAVA while loop inside the method

Tags: java, loops, methods, while-loop

Brand New to Java.. I need to create a method `Sum` to include a `while` loop. The method will take one parameter and calculate the sum up to that number. This is what I have:

```
public class Summing {

public static void main(String [] args){

    double result=5;

    Summing mySum=new Summing();

    double Sum = mySum.Sum(result);

    System.out.printf("\nthe sum is :%d " , Sum);

}

public static double Sum(double result) {
    result = 5;

    double i = 1;

    while (i <= result)

    {
        result += i;

        System.out.println("count:" + result);

        i = i++;

    }
    return result;
}
}
```

But looks like I have an infinite loop it keeps counting..I appreciate any help.

Comment: Hey Ali, would you be so kind and properly format (indentation!) your code? Cheers.

Comment: Don't write `i=i++;`, write just `i++;` instead.

Comment: It's an infinite loop as you increment the `result` variable in the loop, making it impossible for `i` to ever reach `result`. Use another variable to keep track of the sum.

Comment: Also you don't need a instance of Summing to call a static method.

Answer (score 2):

you have written i=i++ ,which will not increase value of i .This is equivalent to creating a variable like this :

```
i=i++ ;
```

is equivalent to

```
tmp=i ;
i=i+1 ;
i=tmp ;
```

You should write just i++ or i=i+1  .

Answer (score 1):

this here:

```
result += i;
```

combined with `i++`

makes the loop infinite, because they both get incremented simultaneously which makes impossible to unmet this condition

```
 while (i <= result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Give another name to your argument ("limit" for instance), and declare result as double.
Oh and the way you've incremented `i` was incorrect.

```
  public static double Sum(double limit) { 
    double result=5;
    double i=1;
    while(i<=limit) {
      result+=i;
      System.out.println("count:" + result);
      i++;
    } 
    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the condition which is putting your code in infinite loop.

what you have done is that in condition while(i you have incremented i as well as result in each iteration which led it to infinite loop.

```
 public class Summing {

        public static void main(String [] args){

            double result=5;

            Summing mySum=new Summing();

            double Sum = mySum.Sum(result);

           // System.out.printf("\nthe sum is "+Sum);

        }//end main

        public  double Sum(double result) {

            double sum=0;
            double i=1;

            while (i <= result) {
                sum += i;
                i++;
                System.out.printf("\nthe sum is "+sum);
            } return result;

        }//end sum

    }//end Summing
```

Comment: is it ok now .. no need to give negative score to right answer

Comment: sorry i just forget to put explanation over there

Comment: And you've fixed that, so it's fine now. Please remember to do that for all your answers. OP and future readers will profit from that.

Answer (score 0):

1) The Sum method declared as static, so you do not need create separated Summing object. 
2) In Sum method you override the result argument, which you put in main.
3) In loop you increase the result as well as i, so i always will be less than result.
As a result, you should have something like this:

```
public class Summing {

public static void main(String [] args){

    double result=5;
    double sum = Summing.Sum(result);
    System.out.printf("\nthe sum is :%d " , Sum);
}

public static double Sum(double iterations) {
    double i = 1;
    double result = 0;
    while (i < = iterations){
        result += i;
        System.out.println("count:" + result);
        i++;
    }
    return result;
}
}
```